# How to combine data from two end points that don't need to be called the same amount of times? [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I'm creating an end point that gives the current traffic conditions and the temperature. It combines data from two endpoints:

1. GET current traffic statistics (at every request)
2. GET current temperature (every 3 hours)

A simple solution would be to chain two promises together, but I don't need to call 2. at every request. How could I structure my code to hold the data for 2. and refresh it periodically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create temperature module with current temperature value, setInterval to update this value every 3 hours.

On your endpoint make request for traffic data, and read cached value from temperature module.